# ODOO - How can I create a Direct Message (not channel) between two users?

Tags: python, api, odoo, odoo-12

I have a system in odoo and I need to initialize a conversation with each new user in the web site. I worked on a script to do that **for each new user** (created by me).  I am trying to run it in a for loop, but it doesn't work.

I need that each user receives a message from a specific group user, like a "attendant user".

```
import xmlrpc.client

## login as admin

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8069"
db = "xxxxxx"
username = 'xxxxx'
password = 'xxxxx' 

common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
output = common.version()

# Auth
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})

models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
message = "Welcome!"


msg = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'mail.message', 'create', [{
    'model': 'mail.channel',
    'partner_ids': [(4, user), (4, 2)],
    'email_send': False,
    'body': message, 
    'channel_ids': [6,],  
    'message_type': 'comment',
    'subtype':'mail.mt_comment',
    'author_id': 2,

}])

Error:

<Fault 4: "('The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.\\n\\n(Document type: Message, Operation: create) - (Records: [3916], User: 2)', None)">
```

Comment: The error appears to be a security/authentication problem.  Have you confirmed that you have the required privileges?

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because you have specified a `related document model` (model) and you did not specify a `related document ID` (res_id).

You can read more at [check_access_rule](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/mail/models/mail_message.py#L678)